# Gradient Layer in Navigation Bar in iOS 11

Tags: uinavigationbar, uibarbuttonitem, ios11, swift4, xcode9

After adding gradient layer in navigation bar, I don't see any right/left bar button items when i run on iOS 11. But the same code displays well on iOS 10/9..

Can anyone provide your valuable suggestions to fix this

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
    setUpGradientNavigationBar()
}

func setUpGradientNavigationBar() {

    let lightRedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(197/255.0), green: 47/255.0, blue: 40/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let mediumRedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(176/255.0), green: 42/255.0, blue: 36/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let darkRedColor = UIColor(red: CGFloat(106/255.0), green: 25/255.0, blue: 22/255.0, alpha: 1.0).cgColor
    let colors = NSArray(objects: lightRedColor, mediumRedColor, darkRedColor)

    let gradientLayer = getGradientLayerForColors(colors, location: 0.5, andFrame: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.bounds)

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.barTintColor =  UIColor.black
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.layer.insertSublayer(gradientLayer, at: 1)
    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.tintColor = UIColor.white

    self.navigationController?.navigationBar.topItem?.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: UIBarButtonSystemItem.cancel, target: nil, action: nil)

}

func getGradientLayerForColors(_ colors: NSArray, location:CGFloat, andFrame frame:CGRect?) -> CAGradientLayer {
    let gradientLayer = CAGradientLayer()
    gradientLayer.colors = colors as [AnyObject]
    gradientLayer.locations = [0.0,NSNumber.init(value: Float(location))]
    gradientLayer.frame = frame!
    return gradientLayer
}
```

[image]

Comment: I tried your code in iOS 11.2 and its working.

Comment: @torap Thank you Sir. I wasted my time in trying to fix it and finally you nailed it. In the name of upgrade, Xcode is pushing a lot of bugs.

Comment: iOS 6 called, they want their nav bar back.

Answer (score 0):

## Swift 5

- Includes status bar in gradient.
- Doesn't use an image.
- Uses transparency so content is visible through nav bar.

```
extension UINavigationBar {

    func addGradient(_ toAlpha: CGFloat, _ color: UIColor) {
        let gradient = CAGradientLayer()
        gradient.colors = [
            color.withAlphaComponent(toAlpha).cgColor,
            color.withAlphaComponent(toAlpha).cgColor,
            color.withAlphaComponent(0).cgColor
        ]
        gradient.locations = [0, 0.8, 1]
        var frame = bounds
        frame.size.height += UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        frame.origin.y -= UIApplication.shared.statusBarFrame.size.height
        gradient.frame = frame
        layer.insertSublayer(gradient, at: 1)
    }

}
```